# How to update OpenJDK 11 on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, openjdk

Debian 10 has OpenJDK 11.0.6 but I want to update to OpenJDK 11.0.7.
How to update or download?

Comment: 11.0.7 will reach GA in mid-April; do you want to build the 11.0.7 development branch?

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to build. I just want to have it if available, considering bugs fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenJDK 11.0.7 is due for release [on April 14, 2020](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/JDKUpdates/JDK11u). There might be early access binaries available before then from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot) or even Debian, but they’d be intended for testing anyway, and could introduce as many bugs as they fix compared to the currently-packaged version of 11.0.6.

Given [the history of Debian packages of OpenJDK](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/openjdk-11), with *e.g.* OpenJDK 11.0.6+10 uploaded to Debian 10 [four days](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1095343/accepted-openjdk-11-110610-1deb10u1-source-amd64-all-into-stable-embargoed-stable/) after [its upstream release](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk-updates-dev/2020-January/002374.html), you can expect 11.0.7 to be available in Debian 10 shortly after its official release.

OpenJDK 11.0.6 was released eleven days ago as of this writing, it feels a bit early to me to be chasing the next release.